# vuejs call function when no activity for 5 seconds after typing in text

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to make something like autosave but need call function only when user didn't type anything in textarea for example 5 seconds

```
<textarea @keyup="test" class="protocol-paragraph" name="" id="" rows="10">{{ somedata }}</textarea>


methods: {
    test(){
        console.log('saving...');
    }
}
```

do I need set custom counter with timestamps or is there an simple solution for this? if I just put timeout it will be called after 5 seconds on every keystroke

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Example with lodash .debounce() method:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    content: '',
    saved: ''
  },
  methods: {
    autoSave: _.debounce(function () {
      this.saved = this.content
      console.log(this.saved)
    }, 1000)
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <textarea @input="autoSave" v-model="content"></textarea>
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.9/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/lodash@4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```